# Python "while" в книге «Python3 и PyQt5 разработка приложений»

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Я начал читать книгу «Python3 и PyQt5 разработка приложений». В разделе описывающем цикл while увидел такой код (см. код ниже). Pycharm во второй строке кода показывает, что итератор `i` равен `0`, а переменная `count` равна `3` (см. скрин ниже). Подскажите, как это работает с циклом while, ведь в коде написано `count = 0`, а итератор `i` вообще ни на что не ссылается. Пытался загуглить, не нашел ответа. Спасибо большое.

ЗЫ: после первого прохода цикла итератор `i` меняет значение с `0` на `1`, следующий цикл на `2` и последний на `3` (цикл проходит 3 раза). А переменная `count` не меняет значение при проходе цикла и остается равным `3`, хотя в коде `count=0`...

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3]
i, count = 0, len(arr)
while i < count:
    arr[i] *= 2
    i += 1
print(arr)
```

Comment: Как работает что именно???

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+while&oq=python+while&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l6j69i60.6394j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&bshm=rime/1

Comment: @S.Nick вопрос не про while

Comment: @andreymal  Пардон, не дочитал до конца.

Comment: В коде count = len(arr), а не 0.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо, сразу этого не заметил. переменные i и count ссылаются на значения последовательно после знака =.

Comment: `i` - *не* [итератор](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). Это просто переменная.

Comment: @wchistow, спасибо, я затупил вчера))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i, count = 0, len(arr)
```

значит то же самое, как

```
(i, count) = (0, len(arr))
```

т.к. скобки не обязательны.

Это присвоение пары паре (кортежа кортежу), т.е.

- первого элемента пары влево первому элементу пары вправо и
- второго элемента пары влево второму элементу пары вправо:

  ```
  i = 0
  count = len(arr)
  ```